# How to change TableView's content by tapping button

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a button which changes `mode` to another value, and then I tried to check value in `mode` by using this code:

```
override func ViewDidLoad () { super.ViewDidLoad()



    println("Selected mode is \(mode)")

switch mode {
    case "A":
        SelectedList = AformulesList

        println("Selected list is A")
    case "G":
        SelectedList = GformulesList

        println("Selected list is G")
    case "P":
        SelectedList = PformulesList


        println("Selected list is P")
    case "C":
        SelectedList = CformulesList


        println("Selected list is C")

    default:
        SelectedList = AformulesList

        println("Nope, it doesn't works yet")
```

So, AformulesList, GformulesList, PformulesList and CformulesList are arrays with cell's label text. In the next piece of code, I did a simple thing:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! formule

    // Configure the cell...

    cell.formuleLabel!.text = self.SelectedList[indexPath.row]
```

But when I compile my code and tapped the button a got an error EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION and in Output was this error: fatal error: Array index out of range

Cane help me to fix this issue please? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Could you post the code you have for `tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int)` and `numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView)`? You're probably returning the wrong amount of rows / sections there..

Comment: @donnywals such a simple issue :D Thank you very much, I have a wrong number of sections in this method!